# Using sqlite browser to extract OSX contacts

Tags: macos, contacts, sqlite

This is following up on this previous [useful answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209942/164749); I'd have left a comment there if i had the rep(:  In case you have the same questions i did:

First, i had to **rename**  `AddressBook-v22.abcddb` to end with a `.db` suffix before i could get my [sqlite DB browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) (Version 3.8.0) to recognize it as a SQLite database, even though sqlite3 could open it from the command line.

Second, the biggest hassle i had was figuring out the data model used in this database.  For me, the DB Browser GUI made fishing around across the tables worth the effort.

- The primary integrating table is `ZABCDRECORD` (Why did Apple have to add `ZABCD` to all table names?!)
- The name of the other tables' attributes which allow them to be joined varies, eg:

  ```
  LEFT JOIN ZABCDPOSTALADDRESS ON ZABCDPOSTALADDRESS.ZOWNER = ZABCDRECORD.Z_PK
  LEFT JOIN ZABCDEMAILADDRESS ON ZABCDEMAILADDRESS.ZOWNER = ZABCDRECORD.Z_PK
  LEFT JOIN ZABCDNOTE ON ZABCDNOTE.ZCONTACT = ZABCDRECORD.Z_PK
  ```

Note that while I'm able to get existing Contacts data in these tables, I haven't found anyway to have Contacts take up any subsequent edits to the sqlite database.  @bmike suggests using vCard import/export, and that is certainly a workaround.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with your question however I wanted to say thanks for turning me on to [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org).

Comment: I don't think you can achieve anything on working on the `.abcddb` because this is a database which is built by `Contacts` from its internal data which is the `Metadata` directory.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What specifically are you looking to modify? Exporting data as vCard and manipulating that file and then importing is the fastest way I know to make bulk changes to the database. That [code is well documented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vcf) or you could import into a simplified sqlite database schema if you needed. Also - if you could stick to one question per question, that works best here.

Comment: hey @bmike, i was pursuing the contacts' `.abcddb` <--> sqlite connection. (if i was starting over, i'd probably use vCards as you suggest.)  yes, i can import into sqlite, but it seems impossible to round-trip.  that comes close to the 'answer' i wish i'd had.  tell me how you'd like this editted to conform and i'm happy to oblige.

Comment: Everything after the code block needs do to go I think. Modifying contacts app to use a different schema is too broad IMO. Basically, can you specify a more narrow end goal?

Comment: see http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Mac_Addressbook